# Algorithmic Stock Trading - how to efficiently process an event-stream for updates of [ Mean, StDev, Median ] values?

Tags: sorting, mean, median, stock, algorithmic-trading

I have implemented a simplified algorithm that maintains stock statistics from a stream of incoming data. The goal is to use efficient algorithms to compute simple statistics, **`mean`, `variance` and `median`**. The program will only maintain one value for each company, hence new values for a previously rated company should replace the previous value. Companies may also be removed from the current list, with a `delete` command. The input must be something like this:

```
A 111.12 Apple_Inc
A 745.29 Alphabet_Inc
A 17.10 Twitter_Inc
S
A 101.33 Apple_Inc
S
A 112.55 Facebook_Inc
S
D Apple_Inc
S
```

"**`A`**" means to input data,
 "**`D`**" means to `delete` data and when asked for
"**`S`**", the program should give us this output: <sub>( `avg` is average, `s` is a standard deviation, `m` is a median )</sub>

```
avg 291.17
s 156878.67
m 111.12 Apple_Inc
avg 287.91
s 158673.31
m 101.33 Apple_Inc
avg 244.07
s 113469.70
m 112.55 Facebook_Inc
avg 291.65
s 156621.88
m 112.55 Facebook_Inc
```

Just as a note, when we have to compute the median, if the number of companies is odd, it should return the bigger number in the middle with the respective name of  company.

The statistic values should always be updated instead making new ones, as long as we insert, delete or add new values.

Comment: You need to show us what you tried and where it went wrong. We are not here to do projects for you, though we are happy to help with specific issues.

Comment: Luis we would need more information and some code to understand exactly where you are going with this.  I would be adept to helping with a problem of this sort given that I work in market finance, but we need code and a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

### The most efficient processing would use a Finite-State-Machine

I dare to state this ( and can behold the resources-footprint / overall-performance / stream-processing latency ultimate extremes ) after almost half-century hands-on experience in the High-Tech
 <sub>( sure, the term high creeps as time forwards :o) but surprisingly not inflating the acquired knowledge )</sub>

Given the rules above, the FSA has quite simple

- **FSA inputs**:
  `{ A, D, S }-prefixed-ValuePAIR-( aListedTitleVALUE, aListedTITLE )`
- **FSA internal state variable**:
   `aListOfListedTitleValuePairsToPROCESS`,
  empty on `[X]`-state ( an un-initialised state ( when FSA "off" ) )
- **FSA event processing**:

as given above:

```
{ onA_aListedValuePairUPDATE, //.CHK aValuePAIR presence in FSA-state + .UPD { aValuePAIR | aValuePAIR.aListedTitleVALUE }
  onD_aListedValuePairDELETE, //.DEL aValuePAIR        from FSA-state
  onS_ProcessAndPrintRESULTS  //.DO {Mean,StDev,Median } on FSA-state + .PRINT
  }
```

---

### A formal topology - a Finite-State-Automaton diagram

```
[X]
  \
   ( .onInit )->---[FSA.WAIT-STATE]
                   ^  \   \   \
                   |   \   \   ( .onA_aListedValuePairUPDATE )->---[FSA.UPDATE aListedValuePair]
                   |    \   \                                                                 \
                   |     \   \                                                                 ( .onDone )->---(*)-----------+
                   |      \   \                                                                                              |
                   |       \   ( .onD_aListedValuePairDELETE )->---[FSA.DELETE aListedValuePair]                             |
                   |        \                                                                 \                              |
                   |         \                                                                 ( .onDone )->---------------+ |
                   |          \                                                                                            | |
                   |           ( .onS_ProcessAndPrintRESULTS )->---[FSA.PROCESS]                                           | |
                   |                                                          \                                            | |
                   |                                                          ( .onDone )->---[FSA.PRINT]                  | |
                   |                                                                                    \                  | |
                   |                                                                                     ( .onDone )->---+ | |
                   |                                                                                                     | | |
                   +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-+-+
```

---

### Design options:

depending on an input stream-processing latency v/s computing powers of the underlying hardware ( as `FSA`-s are so simple, it could be a minimalistic super-fast SoC-hardware implementation ) v/s (non-)blocking nature of the output processor, there might be faster to include a **`[FSA.PROCESS]`** as a sort of "pre-compute" part of the **`onS_ProcessAndPrintRESULTS`** already as a tail-activity after a `( .onA_aListedValuePairUPDATE )->` FSA-transition <sub>*ref.:* *</sub>